# Mearuring distances between all combinatons of lon-lat values

Tags: r, latitude-longitude, geo

I'm trying to measure the difference between locations, without repetition.

I have a dataframe with citynames and lon + lat columns.
The distance should be measured between city1 and city2, city1 and city3, etc.
Until city n-1 and city n.

My tries have been varied, but the latest was:

```
    i <- 1
    j <- 2
    while (i < 51){
      while (j < 50){
        setDT(df)
        df[, distance_hav := distHaversine(matrix(c(df$lon[i]
                                , df$lat[i]
                                , ncol = 2)
                                , matrix(c(df$lon[j]
                                , df$lat[j]
                                , ncol = 2))]

        j <- j + 1          
        }
      i <- i + 1 
      }
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You're totally right, I forgot to add counters.

Comment: Your `df$distance_hav` column is being overwritten on each iteration, so you'd only get the last iteration's result returned.

Comment: You need to create a distance matrix. [Here you'll find an example on how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31668415/2204410).

Comment: Many thanks! That is a duplicate indeed, but to a certain degree. I have a matrix that is in a sense 'double', and I'd just need a list of distances, having only one instance.
As having 3 locations, it would be:
distance_Location1-Location2, distance_Location1-Location3, distance_Location2-Location3.