# Distance between two sets of points

Tags: r, dataframe, coordinates, euclidean-distance

So after looking at various Questions asked here on stackoverflow I'm still not able to wrap my head around the dist function in R or maybe even a distance matrix in general.

So I have two dataframes with xy-coordinates.

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = runif(3,0,50), y = runif(3,0,50))
df2 <- data.frame(x = runif(20,0,50), y = runif(20,0,50))
```

I want to iterate through the first dataframe and for each point/row I want to check the distance to all the points in the second df.
This is probably extremely easy to do and I am sorry and ashamed that I am asking this, but I'm trying for hours now. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You mean `data.frame` and not `dataframe`...

Comment: Take a look at `crossdist` in the `spatstat` package.

Comment: Possibly related: [*Geographic distance between 2 lists of lat/lon coordinates*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31668163/2204410)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the pakcage `proxy` lets you calcualte distances between rows of matrices in addition to providing many more distance metrics.

```
library(proxy)
df1=data.frame(x=runif(3,0,50),y=runif(3,0,50))
df2=data.frame(x=runif(20,0,50),y=runif(20,0,50))

dist(df1, df2, method = "euclidean")

#      [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     
# [1,] 14.502244 15.272563 30.266583
# [2,] 33.152003 44.574128 32.464425
# [3,] 30.112443 42.935810 12.935461
# [4,] 31.749340 38.809452 45.214138
# [5,] 22.712121 25.358099 45.593262
# [6,] 24.702575 31.332886 41.528598
# [7,] 38.244377 46.768200 46.222620
# [8,] 13.686492  1.378374 41.466495
# [9,] 30.884628 40.148856 39.286827
#[10,]  7.615178 19.138047 27.597653
#[11,] 24.898710 22.577377 51.314388
#[12,] 27.962082 39.389227 29.863587
#[13,] 26.927504 39.687474 18.898984
#[14,] 22.249277 26.451882 43.537306
#[15,] 14.632805 24.817799 30.319079
#[16,] 32.483518 41.170256 41.874111
#[17,] 16.471009 23.334594 20.552049
#[18,] 15.561002 27.706218 13.277251
#[19,] 13.375505 19.056233 24.006360
#[20,] 30.191274 42.999607 12.498551
```

Comment: Is it possible to get a similiar result with the dist function in the stat package?

Comment: I've found `Rfast::dista` to be considerably faster than `proxy::dist`.