# Calculating the number of people who live within or outside a certain distance from hospitals

Tags: r, geospatial

I'm new to geospatial stats and can't figure out a simple question:

I have two datasets with spatial coordinates. One has coordinates of hospitals and clinics in a particular district. The other has coordinates of all households in that district.

Here's some mock data

```
hospital_coord <-data.frame(longitude = c(80.15998, 72.89125, 77.65032, 77.60599), 
                latitude = c(12.90524, 19.08120, 12.97238, 12.90927))    

people_coord <-data.frame(longitude = c(72.89537, 77.65094, 73.95325, 72.96746, 
                              77.65058, 77.66715, 77.64214, 77.58415,
                              77.76180, 76.65470, 76.65480, 76.65490, 76.65500, 76.65560, 76.65560), 
                latitude = c(19.07726, 13.03902, 18.50330, 19.16764, 
                             12.90871, 13.01693, 13.00954, 12.92079,
                             13.02212, 12.81447, 12.81457, 12.81467, 12.81477, 12.81487, 12.81497))
```

I would like to calculate the following:

- What percentage of households live more than 2 kilometres from the nearest clinic/hospital
- Create a column in the dataframe indicating which households are within or outside the 2km distance

Comment: Your `people_coord` data errors. Also, are you working in any coordinate reference system / projection, or will the Euclidean distance be enough?

Comment: See [*Geographic / geospatial distance between 2 lists of lat/lon points (coordinates)*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31668163/2204410) for a starter on calculating distances between two lists of lat/lon coordinates and selecting nearest distance and/or location (hospital in your case). You can then easily transform the nearest distance into a logical indication whether a hospital is within 2km distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want, using the more recent `sf` package rather than `geosphere` from the question linked. The approach is as follows:

1. Convert the latitude/longitude points into geometry objects using `st_as_sf`
2. Set the coordinate reference system to a standard long/lat one since the data is in long/lat (this is WGS84)
3. Use `st_distance` to compute the distance between each person and each hospital as a `units` table, in metres.
4. Convert that `units` table into a regular `tbl` because it is a pain to deal with, and check which pairs have more than 2km separation
5. Use `mutate_at` to check each row to see whether each hospital is less than 2km away (`T`) or more than 2km away (`F`)
6. Finally, use `pmap` and `any` to check each row and see if *at least* one hospital is within 2km!

It looks like only the first patient is within 2km of a hospital.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
hospital <- tibble(
  longitude = c(80.15998, 72.89125, 77.65032, 77.60599),
  latitude = c(12.90524, 19.08120, 12.97238, 12.90927)
  )
people <- tibble(
  longitude = c(72.89537, 77.65094, 73.95325, 72.96746, 77.65058,
                77.66715, 77.64214, 77.58415, 77.76180, 76.65470,
                76.65480, 76.65490, 76.65500, 76.65560, 76.65560),
  latitude = c(19.07726, 13.03902, 18.50330, 19.16764, 12.90871,
               13.01693, 13.00954, 12.92079, 13.02212, 12.81447,
               12.81457, 12.81467, 12.81477, 12.81487, 12.81497)
  )

hospital_sf <- hospital %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("longitude", "latitude")) %>%
  st_set_crs(4326)

people_sf <- people %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("longitude", "latitude")) %>%
  st_set_crs(4326)

distances <- st_distance(people_sf, hospital_sf) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate_at(vars(V1:V4), as.numeric) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(V1:V4), function (x) x > 2000) %>%
  mutate(within_2km = pmap_lgl(., function(V1, V2, V3, V4) any(V1, V2, V3, V4)))
# A tibble: 15 x 5
   V1    V2    V3    V4    within_2km
   <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>     
 1 T     F     T     T     T         
 2 T     T     T     T     F         
 3 T     T     T     T     F         
 4 T     T     T     T     F         
 5 T     T     T     T     F         
 6 T     T     T     T     F         
 7 T     T     T     T     F         
 8 T     T     T     T     F         
 9 T     T     T     T     F         
10 T     T     T     T     F         
11 T     T     T     T     F         
12 T     T     T     T     F         
13 T     T     T     T     F         
14 T     T     T     T     F         
15 T     T     T     T     F
```