# Find a best row in the data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data set with some locations:

```
ex <- data.frame(lat = c(55, 60, 40), long = c(6, 6, 10))
```

and than I have climate data

```
clim <- structure(list(lat = c(55.047, 55.097, 55.146, 55.004, 55.054, 
55.103, 55.153, 55.202, 55.252, 55.301), long = c(6.029, 6.0171, 
6.0051, 6.1269, 6.1151, 6.1032, 6.0913, 6.0794, 6.0675, 6.0555
), alt = c(0.033335, 0.033335, 0.033335, 0.033335, 0.033335, 
0.033335, 0.033335, 0.033335, 0.033335, 0.033335), x = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), y = c(1914, 1907.3, 1901.8, 1921.1, 
1914.1, 1908.3, 1902.4, 1896, 1889.8, 1884)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("lat", "long", "alt", 
"x", "y"))

      lat   long      alt x      y
1  55.047 6.0290 0.033335 0 1914.0
2  55.097 6.0171 0.033335 0 1907.3
3  55.146 6.0051 0.033335 0 1901.8
4  55.004 6.1269 0.033335 0 1921.1
5  55.054 6.1151 0.033335 0 1914.1
6  55.103 6.1032 0.033335 0 1908.3
7  55.153 6.0913 0.033335 0 1902.4
8  55.202 6.0794 0.033335 0 1896.0
9  55.252 6.0675 0.033335 0 1889.8
10 55.301 6.0555 0.033335 0 1884.0
```

What I want to do is to "merge" both datasets to have climate data in the `ex` file. The values of `lat` and  `long` in `ex` are different than values of `lat` and `long` in `clim` so I they can not be merged directly (it is the same for `long`).
I need to find the best point (closest point in `clim` for each of row in the `ex` considering both `lat` and `long`)

The expected output for the example is:

```
  lat long      alt x      y
1  55    6 0.033335 0 1914.0
2  60    6 0.033335 0 1884.0
3  40   10 0.033335 0 1921.1
```

Comment: Calculated wrongly, uppdated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Geographic / geospatial distance between 2 lists of lat/lon points (coordinates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31668163/geographic-geospatial-distance-between-2-lists-of-lat-lon-points-coordinates)

Comment: I manage to make working the answer by @andrew_reece and I mark it as an answer. When I will make to work other solution I will revise my choice, Thank you very much for all comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the row index in `clim` with the lowest absolute difference of `lat` and `long` from `ex`, and then add in the `clim` columns to `ex` based on that index.

```
import(tidyverse)

ex %>%
  group_by(lat, long) %>%
  summarise(closest_clim = which.min(abs(lat - clim$lat) + 
                                       abs(long - clim$long))) %>%
  mutate(alt = clim$alt[closest_clim],
         x = clim$x[closest_clim],
         y = clim$y[closest_clim])

# A tibble: 3 x 6
# Groups:   lat [3]
    lat  long closest_clim    alt     x     y
  <dbl> <dbl>        <int>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   40.   10.            4 0.0333    0. 1921.
2   55.    6.            1 0.0333    0. 1914.
3   60.    6.           10 0.0333    0. 1884.
```

Comment: Shall I bother about the `warning: in lat-clim$lat: longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length` when I scale up the example to the whole data set I have???

Comment: @Mateusz1981 those warnings are likely due to duplicate points in `ex`, resulting in groupings of `lat` and `long` that have a length > 1. Since they are all the same points, you can get rid of the warnings by putting `first(lat)` and `first(long)` in the `summarise` expression.

Answer (score 3):

The function `dist` can be used to calculate Euclidean (or other) distances between all points in a matrix or data frame, so a way of finding the points in `clim` that are closest to those in `ex` is by

```r
# Distance between all points in ex and clim combined,
# with distances between points in same matrix filtered out
n <- nrow(ex)
tmp <- as.matrix(dist(rbind(ex, clim[, 1:2])))[-(1:n), 1:n]

# Indices in clim corresponding to the closest points to those in ex
idx <- apply(tmp, 2, which.min)

# Points from ex with additional info from closest points in clim
cbind(ex, clim[idx, -(1:2)])
#>    lat long      alt x      y
#> 1   55    6 0.033335 0 1914.0
#> 10  60    6 0.033335 0 1884.0
#> 4   40   10 0.033335 0 1921.1
```

Comment: Thx, when I want to scale it up for the real dataset I encounter `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 16.4 Gb`

Comment: @Mateusz1981 How many points do you have in the real `ex` and `clim`? and how is the data stored (file, database, etc.)?

Comment: `ex` - 1790 rows, `clim` ca 65000. I import from `.csv`s